# How can I set my points color depending on datetime column in pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph-data-science

So I have this basic chart:

```
ax1.plot(df['data1'], df['data2'], '.', label = 'data1 vs data2')
```

I'd like to color each point according to a third column which is a timestamp. How could I go about it ?

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer if you provided a sample dataframe.

Comment: Coming from R I thought this would be straight forward, I'm looking for something of this kind: ggplot(df, aes(d1, d2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = data3))

Comment: Seaborn is a high-level plotting library that does a lot of things like this. See the [scatterplot docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html); you can do `sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="data1", y="data2", hue="timestamp")`

Comment: or just using Pandas, `df.plot.scatter(x='data1', y='data2', c='timestamp')`

Comment: `c='timestamp'` only works with a `datetime dtype`, which is interpreted as a number, or a numeric column. It does not work with categories. `hue` from seaborn is more versatile.